# My website is blacklisted by Kaspersky. Does that mean it's infected?

Tags: web-application, malware, antivirus

I've been noticing that [an old website of mine](http://stmcp.free.fr) is blacklisted for about a week on PCs running Kaspersky. <strike>Google seems to have dereferenced the homepage too.</strike> The *explore as Google* webmaster tool cannot access to the website.

So I suspect it might be infected by malware. But I can't find it - the website is only made of old hand-written `html` & `css`. There isn't even `js` scripts on the visitor side.

On [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/80a98224e9a4c2962f9069b2c4383d427b640e33a703c3ebccded3e345c669ce/detection), I can see Autoshun thinks it's malicious, without any further explanation.

Nothing has been found by [Sucuri](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/).

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: You said kaspersky blacklisted your website but, I can see kaspersky saying it is a clean site in virustotal analysis which you posted on your question

Comment: btw, I am a kaspersky user with a valid license, I can access your website

Comment: Wow. Surprising. Thanks for the help. On my mother's PC, I cannot access unless I put the website in the white list.

Comment: then, something is inserting malicious code on your mothers PC (or between that PC and your webserver), and you just doomed her by whitelisting your website. Congratulations.

Comment: I've performed a full scan of her pc, nothing bad is detected by Kaspersky. A friend of her has just the same problem on her PC (I cannot see her config). When checking the source code of the website from my mother's computer, I don't see anything unusual.

Comment: @SamuelTb - what do you see when you try to load it? Is it a message explicitly stating that kaspersky blocked it? What level setting does your mother have in Kaspersky's Web anti-virus? Does reducing it help? Your mother doesn't have an add-in like https everywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, "why is an AV product saying that a site is infected" is beyond the scope of the site. We cannot review your site for you.

Comment: @Hector In Chrome, I have "err_empty_response". No matter the level, it blocks. She uses Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10. There is no active add-in in Chrome. I can connect to a random non-https web page.

Comment: @schroeder thanks for your help. Is there a more relevant stack exchange community for my question ? I am truly not trying to have somebody else doing my work here.

Comment: @SamuelTb well, the problem is that you don't have any details to offer us (which is ironically why you are asking the question). It could be a fault in Kaspersky, or an invasive malware. As it stands, there are too many options (why I closed it as too broad). Until you can narrow down what the problem *could* be, I'm not aware of any other SE site this could go to.

Comment: It could simply be that some other site on free.fr was malicious, and Kaspersky labeled every subdomain as malicious.